# Can I repair and rekey this salty security door?

Tags: doors, lock, latches

I bought a new house that has an awesome security door that's missing the latching mechanism.  It has a lock but I don't have a key for it, so I'd also like to rekey it.  I started trying to take the latch/lock apart, and at some point in that process the lock locked itself *and* popped a bolt out the other side, so now the door is stuck open, and I had no luck actually removing the lock.  I unscrewed the screws appearing to hold the door handle on, but I am unable to pull or twist the handle off, it's like I didn't even remove the screws (WD-40 made no difference).  Is there anything I can do to get this door 1) unlocked, 2) latchable, 3) lockable, or do I need to remove it?

[image: detail of lock and latch]

[image: unfriendly bolt on other side of door]

Comment: If you want a spring latch operated by the handles in addition to the swinging deadbolt, you'll need to replace the entire lock mechanism, which will involve dismounting the lock cylinders so you can easily get them replaced or rekeyed st the same time. How set are you on doing it yourself?

Comment: I have no need to do it myself but we did ask a locksmith and got a big shrug.

Comment: Can't imagine why; that appears to be a standard narrow-stile door lock, same type used on most businesses' front doors. Try another locksmith, one who does more than car key cutting and Kwiksets.

Comment: Take it to a real locksmith.

Comment: keyed security lock with (interior) hinge side bolt? GL, google also shrugs. +1. Might need to bring the entire door.... or them to it.

Comment: yup I did google the heck out of it, thinking this can't be the only door like this, but it seems to have come from another planet.  I'll try another locksmith.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you look closrly around the base of the handles, you will see a grub screw. A screw with no head, that is recessed into the hole.

After you have removed those, you may have to wiggle the handles off. Then the plate should come off.

Comment: I did fully remove those screws from the handles but it doesn't seem to make any difference at all - whether I twist or pull, the handles still seem firmly attached and operate exactly as they did before I removed the screws.  I tried soaking the base of the handles with WD-40 and that didn't make a difference either.